# Greens function method for Newtonian potential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

this  may be a silly question but, well you know when solving for the Poisson equation that gives the Newtonian potential, $\Phi$, (for a point mass, $M$, at the origin)
$$\nabla^2 \Phi = 4\pi G M\delta(r)$$
we can use the Green's function method, where the Green's function is given by 
$$G(x;y)=\frac{1}{|x-y|}$$
In textbooks, I see that the only constraint applied to the resulting $\Phi$ is just that it vanishes at infinity. But why is that so? Doesn't a second order differential equation require 2 constraints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing an earlier comment: because the equation is inhomogeneous, multiplying the solution by a arbitrary constant will break the DE. In effect the Laplacian will be a Dirac mass of a different size.

What's really going on here is that the general solution to the equation (without the constraint at infinity) is given by a particular solution (such as the usual Newtonian potential) plus a harmonic function. This is just the decomposition of the solution to an inhomogeneous problem into the linear space of homogeneous solutions plus any particular solution.

Now write $\Phi(x) = N(x) + u(x)$ where $N$ is the Newtonian potential and $u$ is harmonic. Require $\Phi$ to vanish at infinity. Since $N$ vanishes at infinity this amounts to requiring that $u$ vanishes at infinity. So now to show $\Phi=N$ you need to show that $u=0$. So you need to show that if a function is harmonic on the whole space and vanishes at infinity then it is zero. This is not difficult to prove using the maximum principle or mean value property.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This makes sense. So essentially for a second order differential equation we don't necessarily need 2 constraints -- as learnt in school?

Comment: @boogie If we think about the 1D case, a 1D BVP requires one to specify the values of the function on the boundary of an interval. Since this is 1D, this amounts to specifying the values at two points. In a higher dimensional bounded domain, we are specifying the values of the function on the boundary. (Here "domain" means "connected open set".) A "boundary" condition at infinity can be understood in this framework as a boundary condition on a large sphere.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint at infinity is more powerful than a Cauchy condition. Think of $u''=0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If you request that $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} u(x)=0$, then $u=0$ is the only solution.

You should not confuse a Cauchy problem with a boundary value problem: their theories are rather different.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But in the Newtonian potential case, doesn't say $$\Phi(r) = \frac{A}{r}$$ for some arbitrary $A$ also satisfy the constraint?

Comment: Of course, the equation is linear!

Comment: So won't I need another constraint to get a unique $\Phi$?
(Apologies, I feel like I am missing something...)

Comment: Why do you want a unique solution?

Comment: So that I can get the familiar form of the Newtonian potential $\Phi=-\frac{GM}{r}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the source is at the origin. The Laplacian is translation invariant; so it suffices to look at the origin and translate that solution to obtain the one for a source at a different point.

The solution for a source at the origin must be radial because of the rotational symmetries of the problem. In $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, the only radial solutions of Laplace's equation have the form
$$
              \frac{A}{r} + B.
$$
There's not really very much you have to choose from.